# Yii deployment only shows blank screen

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to deploy my Yii website to a Ubuntu 14.10 server, but all I get is a blank screen...

The server is properly setup with the lamp configuration

Steps taken so far:

- I've uploaded the framework folder to a location that is referenced by the config file
- I've uploaded my files with index.php to the proper folder
- I've changed the permissions of the assets and protected/runtime folders to read-write `(chmod 777)`
- I've even checked the requirements folder index.php that yii provides. It indicates that everything is all set to go...

I know that the index.php is being properly accessed because I can turn on yii debugging and see the debug messages.

What's really weird is that the log doesn't show an error and the last entry refers the line that does "render" of my index view in the `SiteController`.

Do you think the permissions of the view folder is wrong? *I also checked if it was the htaccess file, but I've tried accessing the site with the htaccess file enabled and disabled with no result.*

I have no idea what is going on...I'd greatly appreciate any help you guys can throw my way

Comment: Maybe you have a PHP fatal error hidden by your server setup (PHP White Screen Of Death). In your index.php entry file add error_reporting(E_ALL); before defined('YII_DEBUG') etc, etc... also in php.ini enable display_errors = On and try to access again to show what's happening

Comment: Alejandro, you are a livesafer! That term (PHP White Screen Of Death) has yielded a lot of other topics on stackoverflow. For those curious, I used (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1475958/2581016) and found out that I was missing "dirname(__FILE__)" from all my require_once statements. Funny thing is that everything worked on my local dev xampp environment, but needed that dirname for the unix server. Cheers!

Comment: Please auto answer your question detailing solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrapping this up. Alejandro's term of (PHP White Screen of Death) yielded many other topics on stackoverflow.

For those curious, I used the settings from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1475958) and found out that I was missing `dirname(FILE)` from all my require_once statements.

Funny thing is that, everything worked on my local dev xampp environment, but needed that dirname for the unix server.

Now I can continue finishing deployment.